# Mock testing and PHP's magic __get method

Tags: php, testing

I'm having problems when trying to mock objects with `__get` and `__set` methods (using [simpletest](http://simpletest.org/)).

Writing mock responses for `__get` doesn't smell right - the tests seem too tightly tied to implementation. Any recommendations for testing, or should I just avoid the magic methods completely?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you are having trouble?  As far as __get and __set are concerned they have a relatively small domain of use that doesn't add unnecessary complexity to a system.

Comment: I was using a system like the one suggested by penfold - but setting lots of mock returns for __get and __set with different parameters seemed to be putting too much implementation into the tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution in the SimpleTest test cases:

From mock_objects_test.php:

```
class ClassWithSpecialMethods {
    function __get($name) { }
    function __set($name, $value) { }
    function __isset($name) { }
    function __unset($name) { }
    function __call($method, $arguments) { }
    function __toString() { }
}
Mock::generate('ClassWithSpecialMethods');
```

... snip ...

```
function testReturnFromSpecialAccessor() {
    $mock = new MockClassWithSpecialMethods();
    $mock->setReturnValue('__get', '1st Return', array('first'));
    $mock->setReturnValue('__get', '2nd Return', array('second'));
    $this->assertEqual($mock->first, '1st Return');
    $this->assertEqual($mock->second, '2nd Return');
}

function testcanExpectTheSettingOfValue() {
    $mock = new MockClassWithSpecialMethods();
    $mock->expectOnce('__set', array('a', 'A'));
    $mock->a = 'A';
}
```

A bit clunky, but it works.  On the other hand, I think you're better off avoiding them...  the large corporate system I'm working on uses them heavily and it's a nightmare to understand/visualise/debug/do anything with!